# Visual C++ in CLion for OpenCL

Tags: visual-c++, opencl, clion

I have a program for Visual C++ that I would like to further develop on CLion. I have managed to make it compile fine, however code insights are still showing errors on a bunch of things. Foremost among them is certain type definitions not resolving correctly. I have traced them through to the original definitions from the AMD OpenCL SDK, however those definitions have errors:

[image: Errors]

As far as I can tell, the problem with those is that it thinks it's defining the __int8 types. I believe that __int8 and the rest are supposed to be defined in the Microsoft Visual Studio stuff, but I can't figure out how to link that into the project using CMake or CLion.

I'm using CLion 2017.2.3 and have Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community installed.

I suspect that I'm not understanding something with how Microsoft Visual Studio integration would work, but please let me know if there is any further useful information that I could provide.

**EDIT:**
I've done some further digging, and it looks like I must be missing something fairly major. The __int8 style types are apparently Windows only, but even size_t and FILE aren't defined according to the code insights.

Comment: I suggest getting it to compile directly on the command line avoiding any GUI where you have direct control over all include and lib paths then once sorted plug your discovered settings into the GUI

Comment: I've got it all compiling fine, and the settings are fairly transparent in CLion, but I can't figure out what settings are relevant for this problem and where to input them to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a CLion bug. We are currently on it and it will be addressed in 2017.3 likely. Follow the updates here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-9224